# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite, spring-mvc

I am getting **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V** error in the middle of my application when its running,i am using spring and hibernate to connect to sqlite database .

**stacktrace**

```
- Loaded JDBC driver: org.sqlite.JDBC
1203 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.company.project.domain.Records
1203 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.company.project.domain.Records on table records
1203 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
- Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
1219 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
1219 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Documents and Settings\userlld1\Local Settings\Temp\sqlite-3.7.151-x86-sqlitejdbc.dll already loaded in another classloader
- Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@cf0d1f: defining beans [configDataSource,configSessionFactory,configSessionFactoryBean,myDataSource,mySessionFactory,sessionFactoryBean,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,GMEGetController,GMEPostController,HMGetController,HMPostController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#2,propertyConfigserver,sharedSystemForAudio,applicationLoggerObj,viewResolver,applnInitObj,multipartResolver,contactDAO,gmeTesterDAO,scopedTarget.appCon,appCon,scopedTarget.reportConn,reportConn,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
- Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
1359 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
Dec 6, 2013 3:01:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Hibernate-Config2.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3099)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:157)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:184)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:105)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 28 more
Dec 6, 2013 3:01:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ProjectV1.0 threw load() exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:157)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:184)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:105)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3099)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Hibernate config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


   <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:e:\\sqlitedatabase.db"/>
      <property name="username" value=""/>
      <property name="password" value=""/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>        
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>com.company.project.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> com.company.project.dao.SQLiteDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="com.company.project.dao.ConfigSessionFactoryGT">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Dialect

```
  import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
  public SQLiteDialect() {
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
    registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
    registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
    registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
    registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
    registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
    registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
    registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
    registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");

    /* Added Newly*/
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");

    /*End */

    // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

    registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(Hibernate.STRING, "", "||", "") );
    registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate( Hibernate.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2" ) );
    registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", Hibernate.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "substring", new StandardSQLFunction( "substr", Hibernate.STRING ) );


    /* Added Newly*/

    registerFunction("round", new StandardSQLFunction("round", Hibernate.INTEGER) );

   /* registerFunction("min", new StandardSQLFunction("min", Hibernate.TEXT) );
    registerFunction("max", new StandardSQLFunction("max", Hibernate.INTEGER) )*/;
    registerFunction("datetime", new StandardSQLFunction("datetime", Hibernate.TEXT) );

    /*End */
  }

  public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
    return true;
  }

  /*
  public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
    return true; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }
  */

  public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  /*
  public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
    return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      append(insertString).
      append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
      toString();
  }
  */

  public String getIdentityColumnString() {
    // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
    return "integer";
  }

  public String getIdentitySelectString() {
    return "select last_insert_rowid()";
  }

  public boolean supportsLimit() {
    return true;
  }

  protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
    return new StringBuffer(query.length()+20).
      append(query).
      append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").
      toString();
  }

  public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
    return true;
  }

  public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
    return "create temporary table if not exists";
  }

  public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return false;
  }

  public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
    return "select current_timestamp";
  }

  public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean hasAlterTable() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  public boolean dropConstraints() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getAddColumnString() {
    return "add column";
  }

  public String getForUpdateString() {
    return "";
  }

  public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
      String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
      boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I do not understand why it has been thrown and how to handle it.

Thanks.